# Streaming Knapsack in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

I want to implement efficiently "streaming Knapsack" problem in java.

The problem is I have a stream input of integer data coming continuously for example -1, 2, 9, 5, 5, 11, 1 -3,...

The question is to find the first "k" elements in which their sum is "n>0". for example k=3 and n=12, then the solution is: ...,2,...,5, 5.

What is the efficient algorithm for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer in  http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/05/15/streaming-knapsack/2/ as:
(It is mainly for positive Integer Values)

This is a problem of dynamic programming. Construct a matrix with k rows numbered 0 to k−1 and n columns numbered 1 to n. All the cells of the matrix are initially empty, except that the cells in row 0 each contain the null list (which must be distinguishable from an empty cell). Then the items of the input stream are read in order. For each item x, a solution is found and processing stops if cell (k−1,n−x) is non-empty; the solution is the list of items in cell (k−1,n−x) plus item x. Otherwise, for each non-empty cell (r,c) in the matrix, if r+1

Since the matrix is sparse, we will use a hash table keyed by (r,c) instead of a matrix, and for demonstration we will use a random number generator to provide a stream of positive integers:

```
(define (streaming-knapsack k n)
  (define (hash rc) (+ (car rc) (* n (cdr rc))))
  (let ((table (make-hash hash equal? #f 997)))
    (let loop ((x (+ (randint n) 1)))
      (display x) (newline)
      (cond ((table 'lookup (cons (- k 1) (- n x))) =>
              (lambda (xs) (cons x xs)))
      (else (let loop ((xs (table 'enlist)))
              (when (pair? xs)
                (let* ((rcs (car xs)) (r (caar rcs)) (c (cdar rcs))
                       (s (cdr rcs)) (r1 (+ r 1)) (cx (+ c x)))
                  (when (and (< r1 k) (< cx n)
                             (not (table 'lookup (cons r1 cx))))
                    (table 'insert (cons r1 cx) (cons x s))))
                (loop (cdr xs))))
            (when (not (table 'lookup (cons 1 x)))
              (table 'insert (cons 1 x) (list x)))
            (loop (+ (randint n) 1)))))))
```

The outer loop runs once for each item in the input stream; since we are generating the input stream on the fly, it displays each stream element as it passes through. The first clause of the cond looks for the (r−1, c−x) item in the hash table and returns a result if it exists. If not, the else clause of the cond loops over all the items in the hash table, adds a new table item if all the tests pass, adds a (1 x) table item if it doesn’t exist, and loops to the next element in the input stream.

In practice, you should replace the expression (+ (randint n) 1), which occurs twice, with a function that gets the next item from the input stream, and pass the function as a parameter to streaming-knapsack.

We used hash tables and the random-number generator from the Standard Prelude. You can run the program at http://programmingpraxis.codepad.org/WHdBXcyr.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a reverse ordered [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) of the `k-1` highest value integers you have met so far. Each time a new integer is entered checked if the sum of it and those k-1 numbers is more than n. If it is - return the set you've found. Otherwise check if this number is greater than the smallest of the `k-1` numbers(that is why you need the priority queue to be reverse ordered). If it is, extract the minimum element and push the new element into the queue. If it is not simply go to the next number in the stream.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But its seems you algorithm does not work properly on mentioned sample. It returns the result but it does not guaranty that it is the "first seen sequence".

Comment: Hmm I must have missed that bit. So my proposal it that you use the above algorithm to find the first position where you pass the mentioned `n` and than search for the first sequence by optimizing the answer you've found

Comment: But I think we miss the "first sequence" which has the mentioned property!

Comment: I believe you should first find the last position in a manner similar to what I describe and then do an iteration in the opposite direction to optimize the second creteria - `the earliest`